# ¿Porque algunas fotos en mi blog no se ven?

Tags: wordpress, imagen, wordpress-imagenes

Tengo un blog de contenido de imagenes y notas interesantes, pero en algunos articulos se ven las fotos y en otros no se ven.. no entiendo cual es la razon.
Alguien me puede ayudar ?
gracias !!

el sitio se llama [diario viral](http://www.diarioviral.net) y el link es :

Comment: Eso es una pregunta de que la respuesta es virtualmente imposible de adivinar sin más informaciones. Que código se usa para incorporar las imágenes, las rutas de las imagenes, formato de las imagenes, plugins usados etc...

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que, por ejemplo, en _Memes chistosos_ no se ve imagen? Si es eso, edita esa entrada y asígnale una **imagen destacada**, llamada a veces Thumbnail, o Featured image, o de otra forma, dependiendo del idioma de tu WP y de si tienes un framework como Thesis, Génesis u otro. Es algo relativo a la imagen que aparece cuando editas las entradas, en el panel de la derecha. Si no ves nada quizá debas activarlo, arriba, en las _Opciones de pantalla_.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tengo ams dudas sobre wordpress y mis blog, pero las hare mas adelante. Gracias !!